# Forcefully redirect to old url query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Old url -> http://example.com/hotel/fortunep-park-grand/25

redirect new url via htaccess -

New Url http://example.com/property/fortunep-park-grand/25

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write **Redirect [old_url] [new_url]**:

```
RedirectMatch "^/hotel/(.*)" "http://example.com/property/$1"
```

Comment: Its dynamic url 'fortunep-park-grand' is hotel title slug and 25 is hotel id, Hotel slug and id will change on hotel change.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/property/(.+)$ http://example.com/hotel/$1
```

This will 301 redirect changing the browser url from :

```
example.com/property/path
```

to

```
example.com/hotel/path
```